# Calling angular Observable.subscribe() from common file

Tags: javascript, angular

I am calling the below function from two file( ie  x.ts and y.ts) but on checking from third party tool it showing me duplicate code in both file. It is below message service which i am calling in both file.

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.allmesgeObeject.subscribe(data=> {
  if (data) {
    this.x= data.x;
    this.y= data.y;
  }
});
```

Can there be any way of putting subscribe function to a common file and received data it in their respective file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Subject in your service and then subscribe to it from your two components. That way you will call the API only once and both components will be updated with the latest data

```
    export class DataService{
      public allMessages: Subject<any> = new Subject();

      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
      ) { }

      allmesgeObeject() {
        return this.http.get(...).pipe(
          map((result) => {
             this.allMessages.next(result);
          }));
      }
}
```

Then call it once from outside the service

```
this.dataService.allmesgeObeject.subscribe();
```

And now in two of your components you can subscribe to that subject you previously created.

```
this.dataService.allMessages.subscribe(data=> {
  if (data) {
    this.x= data.x;
    this.y= data.y;
  }
});
```